# Maximum likelihood estimator of an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I am working with the above function. I want to find the maximum likelihood estimator.

I found the likelihood function for this distribution, by applying the likelihood function to every component. 
[image]

In order to find the MLE I know that I need to find the function for which this function is maximised. However due to the many components, I find it difficult to establish a firm solution for which I can graph and check it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We maximize the log-likelihood, as it is equivalent:

$$\log L\left(\theta\right)=n\log2\theta+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log x_{i}-\theta\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$$

Maximizing (taking the FOC for maximum):
$$\dfrac{n}{2\tilde{\theta}}-\sum x_{i}^{2}=0\Leftrightarrow\tilde{\theta}=\dfrac{n}{2\sum x_{i}^{2}}$$

Comment: Why do you maximise the log likehood instead of the likelihood function?

Comment: @Flo: since $\log(L)$ is a a strictly increasing and strictly concave transformation, it shares with $L$ its extrema.

Comment: How would I know that this indeed maximises the likelihood function? Would I need to plot it?

Comment: and why didn't you take the log of the first x_i? and why is it a sum and not a product function anymore?

Comment: If you accept the premise that strictly increasing and strictly concave transformations preserve extrema (and more generally, preserve order), then the derivation of the value of $\theta$ that maximizes the function is precisely what I wrote in my reply. You should take the second derivative at this point and confirm this is indeed a maximum, if you feel unsure.

Comment: Regarding the log, you are right. I edited the answer. Notice that this doesn't influence the result as this sum is not a function of $\theta$.

Comment: Regarding the product, it is a straightforward application of $\log (a \cdot b) = \log (a) + \log (b)$.

Comment: I think we can omit the 2 as well, following the same logic that nlog2 is not a function of theta? since nlog(2*theta) is nlog2 + nlogtheta?

Comment: No, because $2$ is multiplied by $\theta$ hence does appear in the first derivative.